# Javascript how to create key:values from a string

Tags: javascript, json, string, hashtable

I have an array of strings in the form of key:values separated by " :: " and the values can have multiple lines. I'd like to know how could I create a hashtable matching the keys to specific strings and map the values and build a JSON file from it? Sorry if it has been answered already but I've been searching all day and couldn't find a way to achieve that.
Thanks, Didi

Comment: You'll need to at least show some sample JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

I din't really get what you want exactly. But from what I understood, this should be what you want. Could you provide some snippets ?

```
var myObject = {
pro1 : "value1",
prop2: "value2"
}
JSON.stringify(myObject);  // outputs the object as json
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
var stringsArray=['key1::value1','key2::value2','key3::value3'.....]
var hashObj={};

for(var i=0; i<stringsArray.length; i++){
    var kv=stringsArray[i].split('::')
    hashObj[kv[0]]=kv[1];
}

alert(hashObj.key1)
```

This will only work for unique key values

Comment: Then you will need to use `JSON.stringify(hashObj)` to convert it to json, thanks @Parthik

Answer (score 0):

For example strings = ["a::1", "b::2", "c::3"].
What you can do is.

```
let output = {};
for (let i = 0; i < strings.length; ++i)
{
    let key = strings[i].split("::")[0];
    let value = strings[i].split("::")[1];
    output[key] = value;
}
```